# Install private repositories on sub-repositories

Tags: composer-php, gitlab

I have two private repositories, let's call them `RepoA` and `RepoB`. `RepoA` is required by the `RepoB` and they are both private repos on gitlab with the port `620`.

Here are the `composer.json` in both repo:

### Repo A

```
{
    "name": "namespace/repoA",
    "description": "My repository A.",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4"
    }
}
```

### Repo B

```
{
    "name": "namespace/repoB",
    "description": "My repository B.",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "ssh://git@git.domain.com:620/namespace/repoA.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "namespace/repoA": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Now let's say I have a project (`ProjectA`), which I want to install `RepoB`.

### Project A

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "ssh://git@git.domain.com:620/namespace/repoB.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "namespace/repoB": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

However, when I run my `composer install`, I get the following error:

> Problem 1
>      - Installation request for namespace/repoB dev-master -> satisfiable by namespace/repoB[dev-master].
>      - namespace/repoB dev-master requires namespace/repoA dev-master -> no matching package found.

I understand that it's unable to find the package since it's a private repository, but since it's inside the `repositories` of the `repoB`, why is it not fetching it?

I thought it would work if I added the repositories to the `Project A`:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "ssh://git@git.domain.com:620/namespace/repoA.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "ssh://git@git.domain.com:620/namespace/repoB.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "namespace/repoB": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

But it still does not work until I add it into my `require` of my `Project A`as well:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "ssh://git@git.domain.com:620/namespace/repoA.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "ssh://git@git.domain.com:620/namespace/repoB.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "namespace/repoB": "dev-master",
        "namespace/repoA": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Now my question is... How can I make composer install my `repoA` by specifying only my `repoB`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot and here is an explanation: [Why can't Composer load repositories recursively?](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-can%27t-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md)